# Problem with program not catching duplicate Strings and correct processing

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Assume I have an ArrayList of food objects foodList. My program does not catch duplicate Strings when I am reading a file, and I'm not exactly sure why. If the String "oil" appears twice in my file, my program creates a new object, when I don't want it to since it should exist in my ArrayList after it reads the first String "oil"

```
while(recipeFile.hasNext())
    {
        String ingredient = recipeFile.nextLine();
        //System.out.println("line " +ingredient );
        ingredient = ingredient.toLowerCase().trim();
        if (ingredient.equals("---")) 
        {
            isIngredient = !isIngredient;
        }
        else if (isIngredient) 
        {
            boolean found = false;
            for(int i = 0; i<foodList.size(); i++)
            {
                Food food2Compare = foodList.get(i);
                //System.out.println("comparing " + food1.getFoodName() +" and " +ingredient );
                int currentFreq = food2Compare.getFrequency();
                if(food2Compare.getFoodName().contains(ingredient) &&!found)
                {
                    food2Compare.setFrequency(currentFreq+1);
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            if (found == false)
            {
                ingredient = ingredient.substring(ingredient.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
                if(ingredient.substring(ingredient.length() - 1).equals("s"))
                {
                    ingredient = ingredient.substring(0, ingredient.length() - 1);
                }
                else if(ingredient.substring(ingredient.length() - 2, ingredient.length() - 1).equals("es"))
                {
                    ingredient = ingredient.substring(0, ingredient.length() - 3);
                }
                System.out.println("line " +ingredient );
                foodList.add(new Food(ingredient, 1));
                Collections.sort(foodList); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, please take a few moments to read through [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Can you share examples like what ingredient values look like

Answer (score 1):

Replace `food2Compare.getFoodName().contains(ingredient)` with `ingredient.contains(food2Compare.getFoodName())`.